# How to prevent Vetur/Prettier from adding new line after comma (TS/Vue3)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, prettier, vetur

How to prevent Prettier/Vetur from formatting this line:

```
import { defineComponent, reactive, computed, ref } from 'vue'
```

to this:

```
import {
    defineComponent,
    reactive,
    computed,
    ref
} from 'vue'
```

Answer (score 2):

That [formatting occurs](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAmHwBM4AzVKOAYQi2gRgBp8c4BDMGVANzhchYArvGIs2ZFjAgAlcgGcWAd3YwwACwF1MIuMXwBffGRx18Ach5C45kExARM3aPOSh2OU0oAKHhK5R2ABsVAE9XewAjHE4AazgYAGVMTkoAc2QYHGt7OHRIvVJiABl2KDShdjS4ADFcdFVucuQQdhEIOxB1GHQggHV1VHh5FLA4RP8h3iHQlrB5CLQoeTg8bxi0huQyYJX7ACt5AA8AIRiweKT2dDhiyjht3f4QQ6PE9KC4AEUhCHhHoJ7EApHArHAtSLsApBTqYHCUGB9VDEGDqZAADgADPY4RAVn0YpgWnC4GC+J0AI6-eDrRwBVryAC0VD0ek6bCpqDY6yqWyQO0BzxW6FQmWyQo+32pD35T3sMChSJRaKQACZ5TFUEF0rR0HyQKSAKydIQrAAqUICAqBVjgAEkoKRYIkwPCnABBR2JGChT4AlYGAxAA) when the line width exceeds the configured [`printWidth`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) (default is 80 characters). I assume your example is just a truncated version of a lengthy line, longer than 80 characters.

Increase `printWidth` to avoid the line wrapping:

```js
// .prettierrc.js
module.exports = {
  printWidth: 120,
}
```

If using ESLint+Prettier (in a Vue CLI scaffolded project), configure ESLint's `prettier/prettier` options:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
const prettierOptions = require("./prettierrc");

module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", prettierOptions],
  },
};
```

Be aware that [Vetur only supports formatting the full document](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/formatting.html), so formatting a selected line does not work in SFC `<script>` blocks.

Comment: Do you happen to know the exact rule as your answer is for code margin, which will not be a consistent fix?